# converting timestamp to nanoseconds

Tags: java, datetime, time

I have a certain value of date and time say 28-3-2012(date) - 10:36:45(time) . I wish to convert this whole timestamp to nanoseconds with the precision of nanoseconds. As in the user would input the time and date as shown but internally i have to be accurate upto nanoseconds and convert the whole thing to nanoseconds to form a unique key assigned to a specific object created at that particular time.
Could some one please help me with the same..

Comment: The idea to use this as a unique key is fundamentally flawed. If you have a multi-core processor it is impossible to guarantee that no two objects are created at the exact same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the simplest way would be to use JDK's support for this. Try following

> TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toNanos(duration)

Here the single parameter duration will be the long value to which you want to convert to NanoSeconds.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The precision of the sample date is *seconds*, the representation in `long` format is a value in millisecond *units*. You can convert that to nanosecond *units* by multiplying it with 1,000,000.

But, in fact, it will simply append nine zeros to the oririginal date value and not add any extra *information* that you'd need to create hashvalues. A `Date` object has no "hidden" nanosecond precision.

---

Java offers the method `System.nanoTime()` which returns a timevalue in nano second units. But we can't wrap it in a `Date` object without loosing precision. Nevertheless, it may help in your case to create unique "time values".

Comment: +1: Multiplying by 1,000,000 appends six zeros.  You cannot simple convert nanoTime to use in a Date as its time is relative to the uptime or some arbitary point. As Date store a long, you don't have to lose precision, you just won't have a meaningful date/time

Answer (score 1):

if you have Date object:

```
long nanosecond = date.getTime() * 1000000;
```

or you can parse your time string if its look like (dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss)

```
 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
 Date date = df.parse(dateString);
 long nanosecond = date.getTime() * 1000000;
```

Comment: But if several objects are created in one second, then this would pose a problem right? For I intend to use this value as my key to store against my object in a hashmap. The time granularity has to precise up to the accurate nanosecond the object was created in.

Comment: @kuki If the original timestamp is only accurate to the second (for example 28-3-2012 10:36:45) as you say yourself then how do you ever expect to get nanoseconds?

Comment: you could use System.nanoTime() as key in the time you want to add the key to your map, or use any other unique value in your object like ID